# Show $b = b(n) > 0$ such that for any $\{n_i\}_{i\in I}$ of unit vectors in $\Bbb R^d$ there is some unit vector $n$ such that $n \cdot n_i > b$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, vector-spaces

Given $d \in N$ show that there is $b = b(d) > 0$ such that for any collection $\{\hat{n_i}\}_{i\in I}$ (maybe infinite) of unit vectors in $\Bbb R^d$ there is some unit vector $\hat{n}$ such that $\hat{n} \cdot \hat{n_i} > b$ for every $i \in I$

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is obviously  false.  For example consider the collection of _all_ unit vectors...

Comment: How does $n$ affect the choice of $b$?

Comment: What does $n$ have to do with any of this?

Comment: @Servaes I think there were far too many $n$'s in the original. I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but I suspect my edited version clarifies things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Posted because the one-line comment was not enough...)

This is obviously false. For example,  suppose that $\{n_i:i\in I\}$ is the collection of *all* unit vectors. Then for any $n$ there exists $i$ such that $n\cdot n_i=0$.  So there does not exist $n$ such that $n\cdot n_i\ne0$ for all $i
\in I$.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you David